# Как заполнить title, META теги description и keywords средствами JS или jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta

Покажите на примере как заполнить значения следующих тегов средствами JS или jQuery:

```
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
```

Comment: почему ты хочешь заполнять их с помощью javascript?

Comment: при переходе на другую страницу сайта загружается только контент страницы, содержимое <head> загружается как универсальный шаблон для всех страниц

Comment: Вы уверены, что это всё будет нормально индексироваться? Если вы просто перегружаете контент страницы аяксом - вы уверены, что робот пойдет, что это другая страница?

Comment: страницы аяксом у меня не перезагружаються

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.title = 'Ваш title страницы';
    });

</script>
```

Коротко

```
$(document).prop('title', 'test');
```

Для description:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').setAttribute("content", _desc);
```

Есть некоторые сомнения по поводу индексации всего этого дела различными поисковиками. Если у вас каким-то способом перегружается страница, можно использовать этот способ и для всего остального.